# Pyspark - how to grab just the hour timestamp in a datetime string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have a df in pyspark that has a date/time column. The datetime is set up as a string. I'm trying to extract the particular hour out of each datetime string and then count how many '0-hours', '1-hours', '2-hours', etc. are included. Each string is set up such as: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' ex: '2016-04-26 19:49:16'. Should I separate the days and times in separate strings or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, hour

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([{"dt": "2016-04-26 19:49:16"}])
>>> df.select("dt", hour(to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).alias("hour")).show()
+-------------------+----+
|                 dt|hour|
+-------------------+----+
|2016-04-26 19:49:16|  19|
+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the timestamp format in my original question. '2016-04-26 19:49:16' @danielsepulvedab

Comment: Well, the answer is the same. Just modify the format according to what you actually have. Let me modify the question to show you.

Answer (score -1):

try regex.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\d+')

exempleDate = '11:11:2020 01-02-03'
print(regex.findall(exempleDate)[3])
```

output:

```
01
```